# Merge multiple json messages from one topic into single json message

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

i am working on a requirement where i have to merge multiple json messages coming out of different tables of a single transaction into a single json message object. I am using Apache-Kafka.

Ex: "Customer Order" is the transaction which has 1) Customer_details 2) Order_details 3) Payment_details
4) Delivery_instructions tables. From the "Orders" topic, i am getting separate jsons for each of the above tables. Importantly, the transaction is started with a "BEGIN" status and closed by "END" status tags in the json messages.

My requirement is to merge these jsons into a single nested json object and push the same to another topic which will be consumed by another party. Please let me know if there are any supporting documentation or tools for this.

I did not find any useful info when i searched for supportive documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kafka Streams join/[`cogroup/aggregate`](https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/cogrouping-streams/confluent.html) functions to group all data based on some information, such as the transaction ID. [Session windowing](https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/create-session-windows/kstreams.html) may help.

By the way, Kafka already has transactional producer support, so explicitly putting BEGIN and END in separate records may not be the best idea. There are other ways to do orchestration across multiple, chained topics where the last consumer in the chain would assume it is the "end" (although it could be converted to producer itself, and continue the chain).